# Incorrect SUM when using two LEFT JOINs and a GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql

The following code returns an incorrect value for the sumHours field. It appears to prepare the sumHours field then once the GROUP BY runs, sum the sums together.

```
SELECT mmr_ID, mmr_projectName, SUM(mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_hours) AS sumHours
FROM mmr 
LEFT JOIN mmr_hoursWorked
ON mmr.mmr_ID = mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_project AND mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_mm = "P90826"
LEFT JOIN mmr_notes
ON mmr.mmr_ID = mmr_notes.mmr_notes_MMR_ref AND mmr_notes.mmr_notes_author = "P90826"
WHERE mmr_mmAssigned = "P90826" AND mmr_projectStatus != 1 OR mmr_notes.mmr_notes_author = "P90826" AND mmr_projectStatus != 1 
GROUP BY mmr_ID
```

Actual Results

mmr_ID - 35
mmr_projectName - Project A
sumHours - 140.2

Expected Results

mmr_ID - 35
mmr_projectName - Project A
sumHours - 35.05

Comment: Please show sample data, expected result, and actual result.  Also, please edit the question so that your code appears as code.  The html tags appear to be messing that up.

Comment: Well, you are selecting every column and then grouping by only one. This non ANSI behaviour is allowed in MySQL, and it doesn't really makes sense if you want to have a consistent result

Comment: The problem is that your joins are multiplying the number of rows, affecting the join.  Can't fix the query, though, because it is unclear where the columns come from.

Comment: I apologize, first time posting on Stack Overflow. I'll update the original post as necessary.

Comment: Refined the query and added Actual Results and expected results

Comment: do GROUP BY mmr_ID,mmr_projectName and see

Comment: Same result with extra field added to GROUP BY

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide sample data in all tables used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was corrected by normalizing the database. The mmr_notes table was integrated into the mmr_hoursWorked table since it only had one unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Due to `JOIN` statements combination of results are returned, so you should handle aggregates and joins separately. Try this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT mmr_ID, mmr_projectName, SUM(mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_hours) AS sumHours
    FROM mmr 
    LEFT JOIN mmr_hoursWorked
    ON mmr.mmr_ID = mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_project AND mmr_hoursWorked.mmr_hoursWorked_mm = 'P90826'
    WHERE mmr_projectStatus != 1 AND mmr_mmAssigned = 'P90826'
    GROUP BY mmr_ID, mmr_projectName, mmr_mmAssigned
) t
LEFT JOIN mmr_notes
ON t.mmr_ID = mmr_notes.mmr_notes_MMR_ref 
WHERE mmr_notes.mmr_notes_author = 'P90826';
```

Comment: Solution provided redundant records - maybe adding a UNIQUE statement in the correct place would move the redundant records? Though it did total the hours correctly this time. A different approach provided the solution to the issue.